# No Cure for a Slow Computer?

Tags: ubuntu-11.10

I have a laptop with the following specs:

2.2gHz dual-core processor.
4gb of DDR2 Ram.
180gb HDD space.

I have tried everything. I have reinstalled the OS. Installed Ubuntu with Lubuntu, LXDE, Gnome Classic, Unity 2D desktop. I have even tried downgrading to XP with all non-critical processes and services turned off. Even with the most stripped down version of Ubuntu it heats up and the fan starts churning. I'm out of ideas. I have tried everything. If you have any tips, please help. :'(

Comment: What is the actual problem here? The overheating or slowness? If overheating is the problem try cleaning out the computer or underclocking.

Comment: have you tried cpufreq ( http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_use_cpufrequtils ) and laptop-mode-tools ( https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement ) ?

Comment: There's no description of the problem anywhere in there. You ask for help with a "slow computer" but don't describe what is slow. Is it slow to start up? Slow to launch applications? Is Internet access slow? Was it always slow? Did it get slower over time? Was it suddenly slow one day?

Comment: @ David Schwartz, @jili Sorry for not making the problem explicit. No, the internet is not slow. Applications are slow to start up. It got slow over a few years. The overheating is a side-symptom.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like something is overheating and the processor is voluntarily lowering its clock to avoid damage. Try cleaning the insides of the machine.

Comment: Especially if the system is slow and the fans are spinning while just the BIOS is running.